# C++ exception to the general rule against using, inside namespaces, in headers

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

Other questions address the general question of putting `using namespace` statements inside namespace blocks in headers, and speak against it.

Does this equally hold for `using namespace std;` or `using namespace std::placeholders;`?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/430766)

Comment: what other questions?

Comment: The short answer is "yes, the general rule against `using namespace` in headers also applies to those two specific namespaces"

Comment: Your own header files should not be pulling in `std` wholesale into the global namespace, nor pulling in `std` identifiers piecemeal into the global namespace.  It is impolite.